# How to set a table to UTF-8 in Django?

Tags: mysql, django, django-models

I am trying to update 2 tables with the SQL command like so:

```
ALTER TABLE sessions MODIFY username VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET utf8; 
ALTER TABLE users MODIFY username VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

I need to do this so that two of my Django tables can link together via foreign key - currently they are incompatible.

However, I need to do this in Django - everything does, including table creation and foreign key linking. Is there a way to set these table columns to utf8 through Django and then apply to the database via migration?

Comment: you very likely want utf8mb4, not utf8.

Comment: This might be useful if you want to make your entire MySQL DB UTF-8. https://www.somacon.com/p588.php

Answer (score 0):

From documentation regarding [collation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/databases/#collation-settings)

> The collation setting for a column controls the order in which data is
> sorted as well as what strings compare as equal. It can be set on a
> database-wide level and also per-table and per-column. This is
> documented thoroughly in the MySQL documentation. **In all cases, you
> set the collation by directly manipulating the database tables; Django
> doesn’t provide a way to set this on the model definition.**

You can always create [data migration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/migrations/#data-migrations) and add altering commands as [RunSQL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/migration-operations/#runsql) migration operation